# PHP system(), exec(), and shell_exec() not returning output

Tags: php, system, shell-exec, php-7.4

I want to find the correct path of MySQL. However, the output of this command is empty.  According to the manual for PHP's `exec()` command, this command should capture the output of the shell command.

```
<?php
$cmd = "which mysql 2>&1;";
print($cmd."<br>");
exec($cmd, $output, $retval);
var_dump($output);
print("<br>");
var_dump($retval);
?>
```

OUTPUT:

```
which mysql 2>&1;
array(0) { }  
int(1)
```

COMMAND LINE OUTPUT:

```
$ which mysql 2>&1;
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
```

Why does the command error? Why variable not contain the output for error since command specifies `2>&1`?

Comment: What do you mean "what's going on"? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php pretty much cover exactly this. shell_exec doesn't capture output at all, and exec doesn't capture output _unless you tell it to_. So... just read the docs and update your code to use the function you need, with the correct arguments?

Comment: What's the point of iterating over the PATH to begin with? That's what the shell already does; better.

Comment: If the webservers PATH does not contain `/usr/local/we/love/obtuse/nested/paths/`, then that's your configuration woe.

Comment: I have modified the code and question such that you may be able to understand better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the issue is not that you not get the output of the executed command, but `which` fails to find `mysql`.
Using `exec` you can get the return status of your command, where `0` means successful, and other values indicate an error.

```php
$output = exec($cmd, $output, $retval);
var_dump($output);
var_dump($retval);
```

If the `$retval` is `1` that would mean `which` doesn't find the `mysql` binary, and returns an empty line.

Comment: Thanks, I added caught the return value and it is "1", so there is error.  However, the terminal command works and returns MySQL path.

Comment: It is possible that the `which` command you run in the terminal has a different `PATH` configuration than what PHP gets. You could compare by the output of running `echo $PATH` in your terminal, and the output of `getenv('PATH')` in the PHP code.
But that is be out of the scope of this question.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem exactly.  The above comment by @mario stated that as well.